# A blue, white and red maze

Tags: mazes

First, let's give to Caesar what belongs to Caesar: this maze comes from the mind of [Dave Phillips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dave_Phillips_(maze_designer)), a brilliant maze designer <sup>1</sup>.

So, for the maze. It is a fairly easy one:

[image]

Your goal is to exit by the blue tile on top left, after having entered the maze by the red tile at the bottom right. And here are the rules:

- Keep to the path;
- Do not turn around;
- **Alternate between red and blue tiles** (i.e. don't pass over two red/blue tiles in a row).

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Check [his website](http://davephillipspuzzlemaze.com/)!</sub>

Comment: Can I pass through a blue one and then exit the maze through the blue?

Comment: Can you go over the same path twice?

Comment: @Mithrandir No!

Comment: @KritixiLithos Yes!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If going over the same path twice is allowed, this is a probable solution. I just started at the end and worked my way backwards to the start since there is only one possibility for the second-last tile (the other red tile would have resulted in an infinite loop)

> The line colour is the colour of the last tile passed through
>
>   [image]

Comment: @IAmInPLS, why you don't accept this answer? There is clearly no better solutions possible, is there?

Answer (score 5):

The solution posted by KritixiLithos, re-posted by Hermansh, and re-re-posted by myself here [below] does indeed work but it is not the only solution.

> [image: Simple solution]
>
>
> In this particular maze it's possible to traverse through every single square on a single run before reaching the end. You can even traverse through every single square an arbitrary number of times before reaching the end.
>
> Below the standard solution you'll find a second solution that passes through many more more squares. I change the color the line several times to make it more readable.
>
>   [image]
>
> No matter what you do, your must at a minimum pass through the squares passed through in the simple (first) solution.

Comment: The fact that you change colors in the middle of your lines is a bit... unreadable.

Comment: There's only one line.

Comment: Yes, with multiple colors, I got it, but it is still visually hurting my eyes :-).

Comment: I tried creating a single line for comparison and it's *completely* unreadable. Sorry about your eyes. :)

Answer (score 3):

Another working version. Though more of a similar to another answer but a unique one

> [image]

Comment: The other answer takes a left after first blue, but this one goes straight. As I said, a slightly different.

Comment: You're right, even if it is *very* slightly different :-)

Comment: Glad you got it ;) And yes i have m +1 for the other answer.