# Go through the labyrinth by alternating yellow and green circles

Tags: visual, mazes

Go through the labyrinth by alternating yellow and green circles. The entrance is the yellow circle on the left-bottom and the exit is the green circle in the middle-bottom (as shown with the arrows).

You can go through one circle more than once. If you touch the circle you must go through it.

[image]

Comment: Can we go through one twice? ALso can we reverse our direction?

Comment: Yes. I will clarify that.

Comment: Do you need to go through all circles?

Comment: This seems very under-constrained, making it feel like there are going to be enough valid answers to nudge this over the line of being "too broad".

Comment: @Rubio How is this question any different to [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47243/a-blue-white-and-red-maze)?

Comment: @boboquack Most notably, the lack of a "no turning around" restriction which makes it trivial to find many trivial solutions

Comment: IMO it's more of a linguistic puzzle than it seems. Feel free to scroll to my answer and you'll know what I mean

Comment: The rules of this question is not very well stated. I don't understand "exchange yellow and green circles"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [image]

Here's the answer. I have followed all the rules, I hope.

Comment: you can go straight to exit from the second last yellow

Comment: Ah, Yes. That is also an option. I am too lazy now to edit that. :P

Comment: This is one of the correct answers. Great job!

Comment: Defining each area between the circles to be a single waypoint, @JonMark Perry's suggestion seems to be the only solution avoiding turns or extra loops.

Comment: @Gerhard; i quite like going round in infinite loops myself, for example right, up, left, down, and do it again!

Answer (score 2):

You can **find** a **solution** using this **systematic** approach:

Define each area with crossroad between the circles to be a single waypoint **A B C D E**.
[image: labyrinth with letters]
Then list all possible ways through the labyrinth, avoid loops, so do not go to a waypoint/color combination you already have in your path.

- Start - Dy (**D** after **y**ellow) - Eg - Cy - loop (only loop continuations; Eg is already in this path)
- Start - Dy - Ag - By - Bg - Ay - Dg - Ey - exit
- Start - Dy - Ag - By - Bg - Ay - Eg - Cy - loop
- Start - Dy - Ag - By - Bg - Cy - Eg - loop
- Start - Dy - Ag - By - Bg - Eg - Cy - loop

You can see, only the second try leads to the exit. So the **only solution** path is

> Start - D - A - B - green Circle - A - D - E - exit

From this path you can derive any other solution by adding additional loops.
For instance Ey - Cg - Ey ...

Answer (score 0):

> > > Since the goal is to reach the end by exchanging Green - Yellow. Having said that and knowing that the *"player"* is standing on the original yellow circle, it follows that with each swap the Green Circle trades places with a Yellow Circle, and so does the *"player"*.
> >
> > In other words:
> >
> > > You don't need to alternate between yellow and green circles. You can only swap your current circle with a green circle (because you're always in yellow)

I have to put the image like this because I'm failing at conceiling it, Im sorry:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqThd.jpg

Comment: I'm not sure that this is what the OP wanted, but it's technically correct and it's a creative answer (and also the first one I thought of). +1!

Comment: If this is the intended answer then https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/words_that_end_in_gry.png applies